# Каким образом делается странички пользователей через php, phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, соцсети

После регистрации надо чтобы пользователь попал на свой профиль с своими данными и чтобы другие пользователи могли просматривать его данные тоже.
Для этого надо для каждого юзера создавать файл?

Comment: Пишете свою соцсеть? Вам понадобится один файл, которому в качестве get-параметра будете передавать id того пользователя, чей профиль захотите посмотреть.

Comment: да курсач делаю :) а как заносить туда информацию его?

Comment: Ну, если вы уже сделали логин, то для самого пользователя показываете форму, при отправке которой заполняются поля профиля.

Comment: да но потом пользователь может заходит на другие профили пользователей где информация другая??

Comment: Да, будет другой id  в гет-параметре и загрузятся поля другого профиля. Что-то мне страшно спрашивать, где такие курсовые дают.

Comment: спс), в Казахстане)